# Mobile Native Project with React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to native (ios swift android java) project into react native code(component or page). I know react native website tell "how to write react native and native code [ios](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios) "(native modules) but this doesn't solve my idea.

For example:
I write calendar component with react native and i have ios xcode project in app store.I want to call tabbar get a page calendar and maybe use User or apiUrl but it's in swift code.

How do you think it is done?

I know facebook team use market place screen ([market place](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/08/07/react-native-performance-in-marketplace) ) and settings page use react native others screen swift or objective-c project.

Thank you.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for ignite cli

`https://github.com/infinitered/ignite`

This is easy to use and will solve your calendar component issue

Comment: this not solution, calendar simple example,

Comment: You want calendar example in react native code ? If yes then why don't you go for react native calendar. 

```https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars```

Comment: i dont want calendar , it's sample calender maybe for example custom tabview , i want how to export react-native component in swift&xcode project.

Comment: To export react native components in to xcode project you need to create ios bundle through react native cli commands.

```
react-native link package-name 
react-native eject 
react-native bundle
```

Try one of those. react native will regenerate the files into ios and android in native code.